# Copy Entity ID at persist time

Tags: jpa, entity, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I want to copy the entity's UUID, generated at run time to another field.
The entity id is generated via the code described bellow:

```
package eclipselink.example;
public class UUIDSequence extends Sequence implements SessionCustomizer {
    public UUIDSequence() {
        super();
    }
    public UUIDSequence(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    @Override
    public Object getGeneratedValue(Accessor accessor,
            AbstractSession writeSession, String seqName) {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase();
    }
    ...
    public void customize(Session session) throws Exception {
        UUIDSequence sequence = new UUIDSequence("system-uuid");
        session.getLogin().addSequence(sequence);
    }
}
```

Persitence.xml:

```
property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="eclipselink.example.UUIDSequence"
```

The entity:

```
public abstract class MyEntity{
    private String id;
    private String idCopy;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @XmlElement(name = "ID")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

How can I instruct JPA (Eclipse-link) to copy the UUID generated at runtime to `idCopy` field as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this will work (I don't know if EclipseLink calls the setter or assigns the field directly), but give this a try:

```
public abstract class MyEntity{
    private String id;
    private String idCopy;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @XmlElement(name = "ID")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.idCopy = id;
        // or
        // this.setIdCopy(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is possible, but in case of entities inheritance from MyEntity, I may need different idCopy values (for example, setting the idCopy with the id of the root parent). Is it possible to use @PrePersist instead? Does Eclipse Link guarantee UUID existence before persistence?

Comment: You can always override `setId()` in the descendant classes to behave differently. I'm not sure about `@PrePersist` but it should be easy enough to test the behavior yourself.